# C# implementing generic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ienumerable

I have been wondering if it is possible to make say `State` class implementing `IEnumerable<Person>` and `IEnumerable<City>` so I could get all the people living in the state via foreach as well as all the cities. It won't even compile saying this: `Error 1   'ConsoleApplication1.City' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'`(weird)... Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Person
    {
    }

    class City : IEnumerable<Person>
    {
        // City has citizens:
        Person[] citizens;

        IEnumerator<Person> IEnumerable<Person>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (Person p in citizens)
                yield return p;
        }
    }

    class State : IEnumerable<Person>, IEnumerable<City>
    {
        // State has cities:
        City[] cities;

        IEnumerator<Person> IEnumerable<Person>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (City c in cities)
                foreach (Person p in c)
                    yield return p;
        }

        IEnumerator<City> IEnumerable<City>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (City c in cities)
                yield return c;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            State s = new State();
            foreach (Person p in s) ;
            foreach (City c in s) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got what I wanted to know now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `IEnumerable<T>` also requires you to implement `IEnumerable` (the non generic version).  You need to implement both `GetEnumerator()` calls.

That being said, this will get very tricky, as you're `State` class will need to determine which thing to enumerate.  I would, personally, avoid implementing `IEnumerable<T>` twice in one class, and instead return the enumerable as a method:

```
class State : IEnumerable<City>
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
      // return people...
```

In general, I think that trying to make something be an enumeration of two separate types is really a design flaw.  It would be better to have State be implemented more like:

```
public class State
{
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get { // return cities...

    public IEnumerable<People> People { get { // return people...
```

This would require you to change your usage (slightly), to be more like:

```
foreach(Person person in theState.People)
{
    // ....
```

Personally, I think this would be a better approach for both `State` and `City`.  I would write this like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Person
    {
    }

    class City
    {
        // City has citizens:
        Person[] citizens;

        public IEnumerable<Person> People
        {
            get
            {
                return citizens;
            }
        }
    }

    class State : IEnumerable<Person>, IEnumerable<City>
    {
        // State has cities:
        City[] cities;

        public IEnumerable<City> Cities
        {
            get
            {
                return cities;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Person> AllPeople
        {
            get
            {
                return Cities.SelectMany(c => c.People);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            State s = new State();
            foreach (Person p in s.AllPeople) { /* Do something */ }
            foreach (City c in s.Cities) { /* Do something */ } 
        }
    }
}
```

I find this is much more clear - as a City *has* People, but it is not, itself, People, etc.

Comment: Darnit, in the time I took to post my answer you updated yours with the same suggestion. :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the non-generic variants, too! 
System.Collections.IEnumerable is the one without the generic type argument!

Add one explicit interface implementations for the System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator - and make it throw an exception - there is no way you can implement the non-generic interface correctly.

Comment: How should I implement it then since I want to return either all the people or all the cities

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an interesting question, because for the reason that both Reed and Sebastian point out, you need to implement the non-generic methods as well. However, you can only implement it once, and you have two interfaces that require. I think a better design might be not have state implement IEnumerable at all, but have two properties People and Cities that expose IEnumerables. I think this would also be a slightly more convenient (discoverable) API.